# Is there a way to subscribe to new quality questions?

Tags: feature-request

I know of the possibility to subscribe to new questions filtered by tag:

feed://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/cocoa

The problem is there's so much noise in this kind of feed that it makes them practically unusable for me.

I would like to further filter questions by reputation. For instance, only new questions of authors with a reputation > 5000 would be really helpful.

Comment: That's not going to net you a lot of questions. Subscribing to questions with a minimum number of upvotes might be a more promising approach

Comment: Although of course waiting for a certain number of upvotes will mean never being FGITW...

Comment: I understand that this is a narrow search. But I could subscribe to this feed using my normal RSS reader and get a low volume, high quality source.

Comment: You could make this a programming question with the SE API.

Answer (score 5):

While there's no native way, you should check out [SE Question Hunter](https://github.com/marvinpinto/se-question-hunter) by Marvin.

> Question Hunter fetches a targeted list of questions using the Stack
>   Exchange 2.0 API and assigns each question an MScore. The lowest
>   scoring questions are then displayed for you to act on.
>
> What is an MScore? Well it's a metric I made up. You can refer to it
>   as "My Score", "Marvin Score", whatever works really.
>
> This program is compatible with all the main Stack Exchange sites

[image]